# Remote control for Steam

Tags: download, remote, remote-control, steam

I set up uTorrent so that it monitors the Dropbox folder, and by putting there my .torrent files I am able to start the download on my home server.
I love this system and I was wondering if there would be a way to start the download of games at home via Steam.

Comment: Steam doesn't have any such features natively.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Steam does not currently have a remote download start feature.

It's inconvenient, but there's always the option of remoting in to your machine at home via RDP or a VNC server and starting your download there.

Answer (score 0):

Steam doesn't support this. But...

You could use the Windows Scheduler or a program like [Watch 4 Folder 2.2](http://leelusoft.blogspot.com/2010/07/watch-4-folder-22.html) to watch a folder and then run batch file or AutoHotKey script. Unfortunately, I don't have a working piece of code for you so that part (the tricky one) will still have to be puzzled out.

Have you thought of just installing [Windows Live Mesh](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-mesh) on both computers? It has an remote-across-the-Internet feature that is killer. In fact you can remote desktop into one computer just by signing into your LiveID in Internet Exporter (only supported browser), which is super handy at times. But it's not as easy as just popping a file in DropBox.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new version of [Watch 4 Folder (2.3)](http://leelusoft.blogspot.com/2011/10/watch-4-folder-23.html):

> Watch 4 Folder v2.3 - a small (802kb), portable (no installation) and
>   powerful monitoring tool to monitor folders and files activities. It
>   is simple to use and to set, it can monitor 15 types of events and
>   trigger different actions in case an event occurs. Main changes in
>   this version:
>
> - New command line parameter to start WF4 minimized to the system tray.
> - Can use the changed shell object as an argument for the executed program, batch or script.
> - Program to execute support now also *.cmd and *.vbs
> - Can close the monitor while running.
> - More info in the live log.
> - Some minor improvements
> - Add a user guide in english (rtf and pdf formats).

[image]